# What does "removed by you" app status mean in Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play-console

My Google Play store account shows some of the app status as "Removed by you" . But this status is not part of the docs seen here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859751?hl=en#zippy=%2Capp-status%2Cupdate-status%2Citem-status

What does "Removed by you" app status imply?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Answer (score 1):

It means that you unpublished the app. So it's not available in the Play Store. You can publish it again in advanced settings.

Answer (score 1):

This status (**Removed by you**) is shown if the developer has unpublished the app.

[image]

If you want you can again publish it by selecting `Published` in the `App availability` option